# Multiple iOS Developer Accounts

Tags: iphone, app-store

If I and another individual want to publish an application, we would have to somehow create a joint account, and I understand this. However, in the future, if we were to independently publish applications, that would require us to create another developer account each and thus spend another $99 yearly. So my question is: Is there any way where we can both have individual accounts and somehow jointly publish the joint application onto the market?

So essentially, is there any way to avoid having to create seperate accounts for our individual publishing ventures and a joint account simply for publishing **one** application?

Sorry, I am new to iPhone Development so I may have missed something.

Comment: No, it's an all-or-nothing thing, you'll need separate accounts. Also not really a programming question, is it?

Comment: So we'll need separate accounts and a third account for the joint application?

Comment: Yes, unless you want to publish all the apps under the joint name (and with sales stats etc. available to both of you and having to divide up any revenues yourselves). Note also that moving apps, once published, between developer accounts isn't officially supported. Some have reported that they've managed to get Apple to do it, but I wouldn't rely on it. *Developing* your app on one account and only paying for the other account once you're ready to publish should be fine, though.

Answer (score 2):

Your developer ID is a separate thing from your iOS developer program subscription, and your ID can be a member of several different developer program subscriptions. However, if you want to have more than just one account on your developer program subscription, you'll have to sign up as a company rather than as an individual. If you do that, you can add both your ID's to the shared program subscription. (However, you'll have to actually have a company to sign up with.)

Having three separate individual subscriptions is probably the easiest, cheapest way to go. If the $99 is really an obstacle, you're probably not all that serious about building a product in the first place. And conversely, if you build a solid product that people want to buy, the $99 subscription fee shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS Standard Developer enrollments, you have a choice between individual accounts and company accounts.  The only way to get an account that is legally under both your names will be to incorporate and enroll in a company account under the legal corporation name (which could include both your names).