# Publish iOS App Under Two (Joint) Companies

Tags: ios, publish

Is it possible to publish an app in the iTunes store under two joint companies? For example, if company A and B worked together on the app, we want it to say "By A and B"

I'm assuming we cannot do this as the Apple Developer Center is only under one company name right? I figure I might as well ask to see if anyone knows otherwise...

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196191/multiple-ios-developer-accounts

Comment: Thanks! Seems like we need to create another joint account, but it has not been verified that that is possible to do...?

Answer (score 2):

You publish an app using an iOS developer account. That developer account can only be "owned" by one entity. If the entity's name is set to "A and B", then it would appear as you want, but in reality, the developer account would be owned by one company, and also the name can never be changed, so if you ever wanted to publish something as A only, you would need another developer account.